# WHERE clause in SSRS expression for max function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, where-clause, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-expression

I have for example a query with return something as it

```
route value
1      3
2      2
3      4
4      5
5      1
```

then I need to put in 2 textbox the max and the min route so in sql this would be

```
select top 1 route from table where value=(select max(value) from table)
```

I add a image done in excel, how this would be.

[image]

I believe this is so easy but I dont have idea how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

I got using expression, this was extactly expression

```
="Route "+
Convert.ToString (
Lookup(max(fields!value.Value),fields!value.Value ,fields!route.Value,"mydataset")
)
```

changing max for min, for the other...

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query you're looking for would be:

```
With Min_Max_CTE as (
Select MIN(value) as Min_Value
    , MAX(value) as Max_Value

From Table
)

Select Top 1 'Min' as Type
    , T.route
    , T.value

From Table T
    Inner Join Min_Max_CTE CTE
        on T.value = CTE.Min_Value

Union All

Select Top 1 'Max' as Type
    , T.route
    , T.value

From Table T
    Inner Join Min_Max_CTE CTE
        on T.value = CTE.Max_Value

Order by Type desc --This will put the Min Route first followed by the Max Route
```

Then, put that query into a dataset, and then create a tablix and use the Type, route, and value fields to return the minimum route and the maximum route. It should end up being set up just like your excel section with the min and max routes above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this SSRS by using a couple of separate tables. Your example data:

[image]

And two tables in the Designer:

[image]

Since the tables only have header rows, only the first row in the table will be displayed.

To make sure we get the `MAX` and `MIN` values in the two tables, each table needs to order its Dataset appropriately, i.e. by Value by descending and ascending respectively.

`MAX` table:

[image]

`MIN` table:

[image]

Which gives your expected result:

[image]